# Retrieving reverse joins on a many-to-one relationship in Apostrophe Pieces

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have a schema that defines a relationship of `client` to `clientType` like so:

```
{
  name: '_clientType',
  label: 'Client Type',
  type: 'joinByOne',
  withType: 'client-type',
  idField: 'clientTypeId',
  filters: {
    projection: {
      slug: 1,
      title: 1
    }
  }
}
```

In the index template of my `clientType` module (extension of `apostrophe-pieces-pages`), I would like to access the reverse of my join like this:

```
{% for clientType in data.pieces %}
  <h2>{{ clientType.title }}</h2>

  <ul>
    {% for client in clientType._clients %}
      <li>{{ client.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

The [documentation on joins](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/schema-guide.html#guide-to-schema-field-types) describes how to set up reverse joins, but neither `joinByOneReverse` nor `joinByArrayReverse` seem like the right tool to achieve this.

Do I need to set up my schema differently to make this work? I would prefer to keep the editing experience so that editors associate the client type to the individual client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know I am the lead developer of Apostrophe at P'unk Avenue.

`joinByOneReverse` is indeed the right tool:

```
{
  name: '_clients',
  label: 'Clients',
  type: 'joinByOneReverse',
  idField: 'clientTypeId',
  withType: 'client'
}
```

It's called "joinByOneReverse" because that is the type of join (`joinByOne`) that you are "reversing" in order to see it from the other end.

The property is an array property because nothing prevents more than one `client` from using its `clientTypeId` field to reference the same `client-type`. And indeed that's exactly what you were hoping for.

Comment: Aha! Based on the example provided in the schema documentation, it didn't look like `joinByOneReverse` would work in this case, but indeed it does. Thanks @boutell!